# Integrating a function of velocity over time

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like some reassurance that an equation, and my solution (relying on intuition), is actually valid.

Consider a toll road of fixed length, where drivers are charged continuously according to their velocity and the time of day. The total cost of a journey on that road depends on the velocity and the pricing function (and indirectly, the total time on the road). This is described by the integral equation:

$$ C = \int_{0}^{T} \frac{dx}{dt} \cdot p\left(\frac{dx}{dt},t \right) dt$$

where $T$ depends on how quickly they drive (i.e. how long the journey takes given their velocity). $p$ is a function returning the price per unit distance for a driver with velocity $v$ at time $t$.

Now, I simplify the problem greatly by considering only the case where the drivers travel at a constant velocity (i.e. $\frac{dx}{dt} = v$).

It seems clear to me that the problem resolves to finding the average price paid per unit distance during the journey, multiplied by the distance travelled. (Since velocity is constant, the price for each unit of distance is constant also). Hence I update the above simply to:

$$C = x \cdot \int_{0}^{T}  p\left(v,t \right) dt   $$

Effectively, we have the average cost per unit distance (averaged over time) multiplied by the distance travelled.

However I cannot recall how to justify this mathematically - do I need specific techniques of variational calculus? Or is this simple, and I am just missing something obvious?

Comment: If $v$ is constant, then $C=v\int_0^Tp(v,t)\,dt$.

Comment: I think your comment is wrong since T also depends on v, so it is not permissible to simply move the v. Also I must have confused units somewhere, as the first equation only makes sense if p has units like (price per metre) per second. Then integrating over time, so C has units of meters * (average price per metre over all seconds) = price. I feel like what is pulled out of the integrand must be in units of metres, so perhaps it is in fact x (which is the distance of the road - which is travelled in T seconds)?

Comment: In fact I realised in my workings that I did indeed bring 'x' outside the integral, not 'T' as written above. Therefore I asked the question wrongly - I meant to ask how can I prove that 'dx/dt' can be taken outside the integral as 'x'? Which is counterintuitive - but seems correct - and must have something to do with the limits of the integral (perhaps via a change of variables?). I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Constant is constant is constant. Yes, picking a different constant will cause the integral to be different, but it doesn't nullify the method of moving a constant outside the integral **after the constant has been fixed**. Also, the units for $p$ must be price/distance in order for $C$ to have units of price, because you multiply $p$ by a quantity in distance/time and you need the result of that multiplication to be price/time so that when integrated over time it gives you price.

Comment: Rather than saying that $v$ depends on $T$ it would be a better intuition to say that $T$ depends on $v$.

Comment: Thanks David. I believe I did write that T depends on v. I agree that constants w.r.t. the differential are able to be moved outside the integral by definition - what surprised me about the above is that it appears correct to put x outside the integral, rather than dx/dt

Answer (score 1):

You start with

$$
C = \int_0^T \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}
      \cdot p\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}, t\right) \,\mathrm dt
$$

and then substitute $v = \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}$, where you suppose that $v$ is a constant. The immediate result is

$$
C = \int_0^T v \cdot p\left(v, t\right) \,\mathrm dt.
$$

Let's be even more specific and compute the value of the constant, which is related to $T$ and to the total length of the road traveled in time $T$. Call the length of the road $x$; then $v = x/T$.
Now suppose that (for example) $x = 100$ and $T=20$; then $v = 5$ and
$$
C = \int_0^{20} 5 \cdot p\left(5, t\right) \,\mathrm dt.
$$

It should be abundantly clear that
$$
C = 5 \int_0^{20} p\left(5, t\right) \,\mathrm dt
 \neq 100 \int_0^{20} p\left(5, t\right) \,\mathrm dt
$$

(provided that the integral isn't zero), that is,

$$
C = v \int_0^T  p\left(v, t\right) \,\mathrm dt.
$$
and
$$
C \neq x \int_0^T  p\left(v, t\right) \,\mathrm dt.
$$

But let's make this even more concrete. Suppose $p$ also is a constant function, and that $p\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}, t\right) = 10.$
Then
$$
C = \int_0^T \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}
      \cdot p\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}, t\right) \,\mathrm dt
= \int_0^{20} 5 \cdot 10 \,\mathrm dt = 1000.
$$

On the other hand,
$$
v \int_0^T  p\left(v, t\right) \,\mathrm dt
= 5 \int_0^{20}  10 \,\mathrm dt = 5 \cdot 200 = 1000
$$
while
$$
x \int_0^T  p\left(v, t\right) \,\mathrm dt
= 100 \int_0^{20}  10 \,\mathrm dt = 100 \cdot 200 = 20000.
$$
So the version that simply moves the constant $v$ outside the integral gives the correct answer numerically in this particular case, whereas if we write $x$ instead of $v$ we get a wildly wrong answer numerically.

A method that fails this spectacularly on a simple example is not going to suddenly become correct when we introduce a little complexity into the example, such as introducing congestion pricing or slight variations in speed.

---

But you can also do a change of variable.
The relationship of speed, time, and distance allows us to write
distance as a function of time if the speed at every time is known,
so let $x(t)$ be the distance traveled between time $0$ and time $t$
while traveling at the (possibly varying) speed $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}.$
Then

\begin{align}
C &= \int_0^T \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}
      \cdot p\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}, t\right) \,\mathrm dt \\
 &= \int_0^T p\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}, t\right)
          \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\,\mathrm dt \\
 &= \int_0^{x(T)} p\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}, t\right) \,\mathrm dx.
\end{align}

And that is how you move $x$ "outside" the integral.
But note that this requires you to know $t$  as a function of $x$;
that is, you need the inverse of the function $x(t)$ in order to evaluate $p$
at every point in the integral.

Comment: David - I appreciate the time you took to write this answer, However I'm afraid you may have missed that T is not constant in v; if you drive faster, you traverse the toll road quicker! I think you also mixed up $x/T$ so instead let $x=100$, $v=5$ and so $T=20$. It must be something to do with $T = T(v)$; perhaps it is wrong to describe dx/dt as a constant w.r.t. dt. What I mean is the velocity is constant - but changing dx/dt would still change the integral, as it changes the limits. I think this feels like variational calculus and so not covered by your example (happy to be corrected).

Comment: I did do the division backwards, thanks for the correction. But I'm not "missing" that any of the parameters $T$, $v$, or $x$ can be viewed as functions of the others. What I think **you** are missing is that in setting up this problem, all three of those variables are constants from the point of view of the integral, because this integral merely computes what the total "price" will be **if** the vehicle drives the distance it drives in the time it drives at the speeds that it drives. All of these parameters can be varied while setting up the integral, but not while evaluating it.